# Trac 1.0.1 + How to link two custom fields

Tags: trac

I am using Trac 1.0.1 with agilo. In agilo, I have two custom fields say, "Application" and "AppType". Is there any way I can link the two custom fileds. For example:

If I select, App1 in the `Application` Filed, in the `AppType` Filed It should show only Type1 and Type3. If I Select App2 in the `Application` Field, only Type2 It should show in the `App_Type` Filed.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of behaviour is implemented by the "chained fields" plugin: http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/TracTicketChainedFieldsPlugin